# Unable to access Airflow REST API

Tags: airflow

I have setup airflow in my local machine. I am trying to access the below airflow link:
http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/test/

I am getting **Airflow 404 = lots of circles**

I have tried to set auth_backend to default, but no luck.

What changes do i need to make in **airflow.cfg** to be able to make REST API calls to airflow for triggering DAGs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimental API is disabled by default in Airlfow 2. It was used in 1.10 but it has been deprecated and disabled by default in Airflow 2. Instead you should use the fully-fledged REST API which uses completely different URL scheme:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html

In Airflow UI you can even browse and try the API (just look at the menus of Airflow).